# Any way to accomplish this in regex without negative lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I would like to format a regex query so that it matches on all newline characters that are not preceded by a comma followed by any amount of whitespace.

For example, in this scenario:

```
Line One,
Line Two
Line Three
Line Four,     <-- whitespace before newline
Line Five
```

I want the regex to return on the newline chars on Line Two, Line Three, or Line Five, but not Line One and Line Four. I have tried negative look-behind but would like to avoid using that if possible due to fixed width restrictions. Is there a way to accomplish this without negative look-behind?

The end goal is to only have lines that end with a comma. I'm trying to do a substitute on the newline chars that don't have a comma + (whitespaces) before them.

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\,\s*)\n','',string)
```

The end result should be:

```
Line One,
Line TwoLine ThreeLine Four,     
Line Five
```

However, the * quantifier before the \s is an issue for this solution.

Comment: So, match the newline character at the end of any line that has a comma in it?

Comment: I'm not a Python programmer (yet), but in PowerShell I would write code that grabs the groups instead of matches and the regex would be something like this: https://regex101.com/r/V6CcIf/1

Comment: Not just any line that has a comma, I want it only match if the comma + any amount of space appears right before the newline.

Comment: You're right, I fixed my question.

Comment: Use of a negative lookbehind is not an option anyway as Python's standard regex engine does not support *variable-length* lookbehinds (i.e., to account for zero or more whitespaces between the comma and newline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd match **all** newlines and just leave the comma-space-prefixed ones as they are.

```py
import re

s = '''Line One,
Line Two
Line Three
Line Four,     
Line Five
'''

print(re.sub(r'(,\s*\n)|\n', r'\1', s))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3yzJzC_KLShSKUrm4ihVsFdTV1X0y81IV_PNSdbjArJDyfCgjoyg1FcJ0yy8t0lEAASg_syyVC6iVi6ugKDOvRKMoVa-4NEmjSF1DJ6ZYKyZPsyYmT11HoUg9xhBIFWtqQmyHOgLmGAA)

---

Or, work on the reverse string with a negative look-**ahead**:

```py
import re

s = '''Line One,
Line Two
Line Three
Line Four,     
Line Five
'''

print(re.sub(r'\n(?!\s*,)', '', s[::-1])[::-1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY36zJzC_KLShSKUrm4ihVsFdTV1X0y81IV_PNSdbjArJDyfCgjoyg1FcJ0yy8t0lEAASg_syyVC6iVi6ugKDOvRKMoVa-4NEmjSD0mT8NeMaZYS0dTXQdoto5CcbSVla5hrCaUgrgC6hiYowA)

Comment: Thank you! The first solution was what I was looking for. I'm fairly new to regex but I'm assuming r'\1' is substituting group 1 (,\s*\n) with ''?

Comment: @RobertLu No, it substitutes group 1 with **itself** (and substitutes *other* newlines with nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9tC3xU/1))

```py
import re

text = """\
Line One,
Line Two
Line Three
Line Four,
Line Five
"""

print(re.sub(r"(?<!,|\s)\s*\n", "", text))
```

Prints:

```
Line One,
Line TwoLine ThreeLine Four,
Line Five
```

Comment: Though if you for example add a space at the end of line 2, this removes it.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
st = '''Line One,
Line Two
Line Three
Line Four,     
Line Five'''
```

You can capture each line all in one go and use a lambda to consider what you got:

```
import re

pat=re.compile(r'(?m)^(.*?(,\s*)?)(\n|\Z)')

print(pat.sub(lambda m: m.group(0) if m.group(2) else m.group(1), st))

# or print(pat.sub(lambda m: m[0] if m[2] else m[1], st))
```

Prints:

```
Line One,
Line TwoLine ThreeLine Four,     
Line Five
```

The second match group is only *truethy* if the optional group `(,\s*)?` matches. If that is the case, use whole line in the replacement. If the second match group is `None` just use the first part of the line represented by `.*?` which does not include the `\n`.

You can also accomplish this without a regex at all with Python string functions:

```
 print(''.join([f'{line}\n' if line.rstrip().endswith(',') else line 
         for line in st.splitlines()]))
 # same output
```

Comment: Just a shorter lambda: `m[0 if m[2] else 1]` (even `m[not m[2]]` works, but I find it less clear).

Comment: Is "all in one go" in contrast to the other solutions?

Comment: @KellyBundy: As opposed to a look around of any sort.